# cannot open Eclipse editor anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

HELP, i need this for school
i did cut out some of my projects from the projects folder, because there were too many in my workspace
now Eclipse does not open the remaining project anymore, getting this error.

Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.text.normalizer.ReplaceableUCharacterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.text.normalizer.UCharacterIterator.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.setText(Unknown Source)
at java.text.CollationElementIterator.setText(Unknown Source)
at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1188)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.init(BPELEditor.java:1539)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:237)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createDesignPage(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:459)
at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createPages(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:515)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:49)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: Create a new workspace and import your projects.

Comment: i created a new workspace and imported the old project and still get the same error, i am screwed

Comment: @sakal I hope you learned two things; Backup your code and use version control.

Comment: Have you tried launching eclipse in clean mode?

Comment: yes i did, there is clean install on this computer, same problem, i had just cut out a couple of folders that i did not need anymore form the workspace and now nothing works anymore

Comment: If all else fails, create a new `WorkSpace`, create a `New Project`, and just copy over the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had accidentally moved the metadata folder with all the other folders. So i move that folder into a new empty folder and set that as the new workspace. Afterwards i pasted my projects into this new workspace and it all works again.